# img src root relative path not working

Tags: html, laravel, path

I have two routes mapped to the same html, generated with php blade template engine in laravel.

```
<img src="/images/logotype.svg" alt="">
```

The routes are

```
mydomain.com
mydomain.com/subscribers/1/edit
```

The first route works fine, finding the image at mydomain.com/images/logotype.svg

But the second route gives a broken image with image url like: mydomain.com/subscribers/1/edit/images/logotype.svg

From what I have read I have the right syntax for root relative paths in the html. What other error sources can I look for?

---

The html also includes js and css files. In that case it works fine for all routes like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
```

Comment: I had left over duplicate create/edit views so this was never a real error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `asset()` helper for generating full url of assets:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/logotype.svg') }}" alt="">
```

This will find the image from `public/images/logotype.svg` folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add svg

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/logotype.svg"></object>
```